# EAFlashUpload with ASP.NET 4.0 failes in Firefox, Chrome but works in IE

Tags: asp.net, flash, upload

I'm using EAFlashUpload component with ASP.NET 4.0 on my site to allow for multiple file uploads (select multiple files at a time).

The component works great and with no issues with IE (7, 8, 9), but with Firefox or Chrome, it gives an "unknown http error" after a file is uploaded (when it is trying to do postback to the server, I think).

I'm running this under IIS7 on Windows 2008 Server R2, but I don't think the version of IIS or Windows is the significant factor.

This is the client side Javascript to handle the component:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var params = { BGcolor: "#ffffff", wmode: "window" };
    var attributes = { id: "EAFlashUpload", name: "EAFlashUpload" };
    var flashvars = new Object();
    var uploadUrl = "Pages/SendAdvanced.aspx";
    //if (!document.all) {
    //    uploadUrl = "../" + uploadUrl;
    //}
    flashvars["uploader.uploadUrl"] = uploadUrl;
    flashvars["viewFile"] = "EAFUpload/TableView.swf";
    flashvars["view.removeButton.visible"] = "false";
    flashvars["view.clearButton.visible"] = "false";
    flashvars["queue.filesCountLimit"] = "10";
    flashvars["queue.fileSizeLimit"] = "2147483648";        // 2 gigabytes = 2147483648 bytes
    swfobject.embedSWF("EAFUpload/EAFUpload.swf", "EAFlashUpload_holder", "650", "380", "10.0.0", "EAFUpload/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    function EAFlashUpload_onMovieLoad(errors) { if (errors != "") alert(errors); }
</script>
```

EDIT:
I discovered after further testing that the Flash component is throwing error #2038, which is a generic catchall error for "cannot connect to the server".  Not sure why this is an issue with Chrome and FF, but this warrants additional investigation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and it is absolutely NOT what I was expecting.

This line of code was the issue:

```
var uploadUrl = "Pages/SendAdvanced.aspx";
```

That line is a relative path, set in client side Javascript and used by the Flash component to know where to post the content.

When I changed it to this, it worked:

```
var uploadUrl = "http://www.mysite.com/Pages/SendAdvanced.aspx";
```

What I would love for someone to tell me is WHY the first line of code EVER works?  Why does it work in Internet Explorer?  Is there something special it is able to do to track relative paths, that the other browsers (and the Mac) won't do?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer when I was experiencing similar issues with the flash uploader (the uploads would fail before even connecting to the server). Using the following example code:

```
var uploadUrl = location.href;
if (!document.all) {
    uploadUrl = "../" + uploadUrl;
}
//alert(uploadUrl);

var flashvars = new Object();
flashvars["uploader.uploadUrl"] = uploadUrl;
...
```

Turns out the problem only occurred with URLs that had a **&** and/or **#** in them (the flash object was receiving these and not knowing what to do with them because they were not encoded). **There are more characters than these to worry about, however, in my case, this ended up solving the issue**

I simply replaced the ampersands with the encoded version that flash was expecting, and removed the hash pound and everything following it (because it is useless from a server's perspective).

```
uploadUrl = uploadUrl.replace(/\&/g, '%26');
uploadUrl = uploadUrl.replace(/#.*/g, '');
```